# How convert a DC2type:array in JSON and JSON in DC2TYPE via javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, doctrine-orm

I need to use javascript in (node.js server) for encode and decode DC2type:array in JSON object.

I want transform

```
a:4:{i:0;s:7:"stringa";i:1;i:1;i:2;d:2.5;i:3;a:3:{s:6:"chiave";s:6:"valore";s:3:"key";s:5:"value";s:5:"other";a:3:{i:0;i:1;i:1;s:1:"a";i:2;d:2.5;}}}
```

into

```
['stringa', 1, 2.5, {chiave: 'valore', key: 'value', other: [1, 'a', 2.5]}]
```

I've this functions

```
var array_dc2type = function(data) {
    var inner = '';
    i = 0;
    data.each(function(elem) {
        inner += 'i:' + i + ';s:' + elem.length + ':"' + elem + '";';
        i++;
    });
    return 'a:' + data.length + ':{' + inner + '}';
};

var dc2type_array = function(data) {
    data = data.replace(/(a|s|i):[0-9]+(:|;)/g, '').replace(/\{/g, '[').replace(/[;]?\}/g, ']').replace(/;/g, ',');
    return eval(data);
};
```

but they are very limited (they solve only string array case)

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

I solve with

http://phpjs.org/functions/serialize/

and

http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize/

DC2Type is only PHP serialization and unserialization